# C++ If Else statement Problems

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax

My code contains an If Else statement. I want it to validate a string that a user inputs puts into the script on two things:

- The length of the string has to be more than 0
- The string has to consist of alphabet characters

Below is my code, I think the error is to do with the length of the string piece of code.

Before Edit:

```
cout << "Your word: " << szOriginal << "\n";
if szOriginal.length() > 0 and (isalpha(szOriginal))
{
    szWord = szOriginal.tolower();
    cout << szWord << "\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid word." << endl;
}
```

Sorry guys, the error produced by Dev-C++ is

> expected '(' before "szOriginal"

Link to printscreen: http://gyazo.com/b3f43928072e9c2a5a8a712a9030364d

After Edit with variable declaration and such:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    string original;
    cout << "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!\n";
    cout << "Type a word you wish to translate:\n";
    cin >> original;
    cout << "Your word: " << original << "\n";
    if (original.length() > 0 && (isalpha(original)) ) 
    {
        word = original.tolower();
        cout << Word << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid word." << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

So sorry for this bad post!

Comment: Produce an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and post full errors.

Comment: What error? Are you really missing the `( )` around your `if` clause?

Comment: missing bracket `( )`

Comment: Also, without seeing the declaration, I would assume your "string" variables are actually `char []` based on the name. This is also wrong, you need `std::string` for C++ strings that have methods (but *don't* have `.tolower()`.

Comment: Also look up how to use `isAlpha` -- it does not work on strings.

Comment: Move the left-parenthesis that's to the left of `isalpha` so that it's to the left of the leftmost `szOriginal`. That fixes the `if` statement and, as an added bonus, removes a redundant pair of parentheses.

Comment: "My simple script contains an If Else statement."
I don't think you can call C++ code a script

Comment: The variable is a string as I declared it a string, I'm guessing I should remove the "sz" part of the variable name. I got this off C++ for Dummies...

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that either - and you're right, I come from a Python background.

Comment: Should have read a basic C++ tutorial...

Comment: I'm reading through C++ for Dummies, I haven't met if else statements yet, this was purely just for throwing myself in the deep end and seeing what I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

`if ( [...] )` - you're missing the brackets.

Also, it's `&&` instead of `and`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are coming from a python background

```
cout << "Your word: " << szOriginal << "\n";
if (szOriginal.length() > 0 && (isalpha(szOriginal)) )
{
    szWord = szOriginal.tolower();
    cout << szWord << "\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid word." << endl;
}
```

you need `( )` around the `if` condition, and use `&&` for logical and

**EDIT**
you are using `szOriginal` as a `char` when you say `isalpha(szOriginal)`
and as an object when you say `szWord = szOriginal.tolower();`
so you need to look into that also